# Storing and retrieving IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

There's a million questions on SO about the best way to store IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on a PHP/MySQL setup, but the answers are either out of date (only IPv4) or they're contradictory/incomplete.

I've created this question to go with a clear answer that gives you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you only had to worry about IPv4, you could use PHP's `ip2long` and `long2ip` to quickly and easily convert an IP address to a integer. These days, however, nearly everyone should expect to come across some IPv6 addresses at some point, and that's something that's only going to increase.

A common and efficient solution to have both is to use **PHP**'s [inet_pton function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) (which handles both IPv4 and v6), and then store the result in a `VARBINARY(16)` column in your database.

So, let's say we have an IPv6 address like: `FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329`

When converted with `inet_pton` and stored in a `VARBINARY(16)` column it looks like this:

`0xfe800000000000000202b3fffe1e8329`

You can then retrieve this from your database and display it using `inet_ntop`.

Eg:

```
echo inet_ntop($ipAddressFromDB);
```

This is a quick and efficient way to store IP addresses in an MySQL database.

Comment: MySQL itself offers equivalent functions [`INET_ATON()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) for IPv4 and, [since v5.6.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-3.html), [`INET6_ATON()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) and [`INET6_NTOA()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-ntoa) for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not only need to worry about ip2long and long2ip; as eggyal says there are mysql functions too, however the latter are (correctly) unsigned while the former are signed, I.e. incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time you're doing yourself a disservice if you're not building your application to accommodate IPv6, and this is going to become even more true over time. For this reason I've started storing *all* IP addresses in IPv6 format, and using [6to4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4) notation for IPv4 addresses.

The TL;DR for 6to4 is:

> The first 16 bits of the prefix are always 2002:, the next 32 bits are the IPv4 address, and the last 16 bits of the prefix are [not important for this purpose]

So let's say that your IP address is `222.173.190.239`, we convert that to 6to4 notation by:

```
sprintf('2002:%s::', implode(':', str_split(str_pad(dechex(ip2long($addr)), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), 2)));
```

Which becomes: `2002:de:ad:be:ef::`

Which you convert to binary form for storage by: `inet_pton('2002:de:ad:be:ef::');`

Which gives the 16-byte binary: `0x200200de00ad00be00ef000000000000`

Which should be easily store-able and searchable.

I've previously written a helper class for this, and I've just pushed it up to [Github](https://github.com/wrossmann/sixtofour) and [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/sixtofour) in case someone else might find it useful.